# Is it permission for a muslim to sing and listen music?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, music

Is it permission for a muslim to sing song and listen music in islam..what music from islamic point of view and is not good then what punishment for that.

Answer (score -2):

### In the name of Allah, the Beneficent, Most Merciful

**All praise and thanks are due to Allah, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in God from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever Allah guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but Allah, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**YOUR QUESTION:** It is permissible for a Muslim to sing and listen to music?

**Answer:** No, that is prohibited in Islam. Some scholars have the opinion that music is permissible so as long as there is no evil in it. But majority of scholars have opinion that musical instruments are prohibited based on the quotes below.

### 1. Listening to music

The verse of the Quraan and the narration of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) indicate that musical instruments are condemned, and warn us against them. The Quraan teaches that playing these instruments is one of the things that leads people astray and constitutes mockery of the Signs of Allah. Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> "And of the people is he who buys the amusement of speech to mislead [others] from the way of Allah without knowledge and who takes it in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment." [[**Luqman, 31:6**](https://quran.com/31/6)]

Allah Says to Satan:

> "And incite [to senselessness] whoever you can among them with your voice and assault them with your horses and foot soldiers and become a partner in their wealth and their children and promise them." But Satan does not promise them except delusion." [[**The Night Journey, 17:64**](https://quran.com/17/64)]

It was reported in a saheeh hadeeth from the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: In my ummah there will be people who allow fornication/adultery (zina), silk, wine and musical instruments [maaazif]. Some people will stay at the side of a mountain, and they will have flocks of sheep. When a poor person comes in the evening to ask them for something he needs, they will say. Come back to us tomorrow. Then during the night Allah will destroy them by causing the mountain to fall upon them, while He changes others into apes and swine. They will remain in such a state until the Day of Resurrection.

**Why it is prohibited?**

Shaykh Al-Sa’di  said:

> "This includes all manner of haraam speech, all idle talk and falsehood, and all nonsense that encourages disbelief and disobedience; the words of those who say things to refute the truth and argue in support of falsehood to defeat the truth; and backbiting, slander, lies, insults and curses; the singing and musical instruments of the devil; and musical instruments which are of no spiritual or worldly benefit." [[**Tafseer al-Sa’di, 6/150**](https://muflihun.com/articles/music)]

Allah Says:

> Then at this statement do you wonder?
> And you laugh and do not weep
> While you are proudly sporting?
> So prostrate to Allah and worship [Him]
> [[**The Star, 53:59-61**](https://quran.com/53/59-61)]

### 2. Singing

It was reported from Abu Umaamah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: **“Do not sell singing slave women, do not buy them and do not teach them. There is nothing good in this trade, and their price is haraam."**

The Holy Prophet of Islam has stated: **“A person who possesses a ‘sitar’ will be raised on the Day of Judgement with a black face. His hands will be holding a ‘sitar’ of fire. Seventy thousand angels with maces of fire will hit him on the face and the head. The singer will arise from his grave – blind, deaf and dumb. The adulterer will be similarly raised. The player of flute will also be made to rise in this way, as will be the drum player.”** (Mustadrak al-Wasa’il).

It means that all such people will appear on the field of “Mahshar” (on the day of reckoning) as blind, deaf and dumb.

Allah Says:

> "And do not pursue that of which you have no knowledge. Indeed, the hearing, the sight and the heart - about all those [one] will be questioned." [[**The Night Journey, 17:36**](https://quran.com/17/36)]

If you want to sing without musical instruments, then yes it ok so as long as it does not involve bidah or exaggeration that is condemned by sharia.

---

**References:**

- [**it is correct to sing some songs without musical instruments accompaniment?**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/23351/is-it-correct-to-sing-some-songs-without-musical-accompaniment)
- [**Ruling on so-called “Islamic” songs with musical instruments**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5011/ruling-on-so-called-147islamic148-songs-with-musical-instruments)
- [**Ruling on music, singing and dancing**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5000/ruling-on-music-singing-and-dancing)
- [**The Status of Music in Islam**](https://www.al-islam.org/articles/status-music-islam-shaykh-saleem-bhimji)